# How to do create a table in SQL and do headcounts in the respective hours

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

We are trying to do an analysis of how many staff are there in each department in every hour for trending and forecasting purposes.

The image below is the outcome I would like to get
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMtaP.png
2am means the number of employees clocked in from 2:00am to 2:59am

We would be putting the query into tableau software for analyzing. Btw I am using mssql 2014.

We have the following columns to do the query

```
SHIFTA_Start     = Clock in Time (VARCHAR)   
SHIFTA_End       = Clock out Time (VARCHAR)   
EMPLOYEENAME     = Name of the Employee     
DEPARTMENT       = Department of the Employee  
ATTENDANCEDATE   = Date the employee come for work (VARCHAR)   
WEEKDAYSTR       = Mon, Tues, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Whats the cut off for 2am? they've got to be signed in by 2am or before 3am? Are you trying to do this in Tableau or SQL Server?

Comment: I have tried doing case statement to count the accumulated employees working hours for the individual department (query can be found on my profile), but what I want to get is just the headcount.  

2am means the number of employees clock in from 2am to 259am  

I am doing in SQL server now as it would be quite messy if I do it in tableau, once done I can put the queries in tableau for analyzing. 
@RichBenner

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, modify based on your requirement.

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT,
(SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEENAME) FROM TABLE WHERE DATEPART(HH,SHIFTA_START) <= 1 AND DATEPART(HH,SHIFTA_END) >= 2 AND DEPARTMENT = T.DEPARTMENT) AS '2AM',
(SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEENAME) FROM TABLE WHERE DATEPART(HH,SHIFTA_START) <= 2 AND DATEPART(HH,SHIFTA_END) >= 3 AND DEPARTMENT = T.DEPARTMENT) AS '3AM',
.
.
.
.
FROM TABLE T
WHERE ATTENDANCEDATE = GETDATE()
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT 
ORDER BY DEPARTMENT
```